# Drop in charging current, could it be an issue in the long run?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-chemistry, lifepo4

Recently, I've noticed a slight decrease in charging current for my 8s LiFePO4 battery after around 7 charge cycles. The charger used to deliver 1.48A, but now it charges at around 1.45A. I'm wondering if this is a cause for concern. Could this be an issue with the charger or potentially a problem with the battery?

Additional info- my charger only charges my battery upto 90% soc and then cuts off the charge hence while it might be good for the battery health, my battery is prone to disbalancing issues since some bms tend to balance the cells only when the battery is fully charged, so do let me know if that is related to this issue.

I use it on my ebike so it(the battery) goes through consistent shocks and tremors and rough use.

Any insights or suggestions on diagnosing the situation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"[image]